# Outlook.com not receiving mails from Wordpress (Works with other)

Tags: php, wordpress, email, outlook.com

I have a personalized email (username@domain_name) setup using Outlook.com and I am receiving mails from all other sources except from `wordpress@<domain_name>`.

I tested by sending mails from following:

```
Gmail=> Works
Outlook (live.in email address)=> Works
Outlook (custom_domain address)=> Works
Yahoo=> Works
```

But E-mail never appears when there is a notification from Wordpress or Using contact form configured to receive e-mail on `name@<domain.com> (Where name@<domain.com> is setup using Outlook.com)`, Although it worked when i changed mail to my gmail address for testing.

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, The mail never arrives.

Comment: Is your website running on Windows or Linux?